# UK ISA - Can Only contribute to 1 provider a year?

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

HMRC has a rule that you can only pay into one stocks and shares isa in any given year.

But what if I transfer this years part funded ISA to another provider. Can I continue to pay into the new provider?

Or perhaps I should just fill it up with cash then transfer it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can continue to contribute to the new ISA after the transfer. You can also transfer a cash ISA from this year to a stocks and shares ISA and then open a new cash ISA.

Comment: It's worth adding that you must do this using the ISA transfer procedure of the new provider.  If you manually withdraw the money, close the ISA and then try and open a new one you will only be able to pay in your remaining allowance for the year